# jquery: Binding event handler to added class

Tags: jquery, html, binding, onclick, addclass

I'm not sure why the follow code doesn't work, can someone please have a look for me? I have setup a little JSfiddle to demonstrate the problem.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="state_1">
        <a href="#">state one</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$('.state_1 a').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('state_1').addClass('state_2');
    $(this).html('state two');
});

/* SECOND CLICK: NEVER TRIGGERS? */
$('.state_2 a').click(function(){
    alert("clicked!");
});
</script>
```

So, the link itself has no class, but is in a "container" DIV called ".state_1". The first time the link is clicked, the class "state_1" is removed from the container, and "state_2" is added in it's place.
(We also change the anchor text to "state two").
This all appears to work.

The problem is, now the "container" DIV should have the class ".state_2", but:

```
$('.state_2 a').click();
```

... never triggers?

Any ideas? JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m5ctkzg2/

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically or **manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes)**.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

*Example*

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', ".state_2 a", function(){
    //Your code
});
```

Thanks @Rory for [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5ctkzg2/1/)

Comment: Beat me to it as well. Should add a code snippet to show it off though.

Comment: Thanks @Satpal, I thought it was something like that! It's worth mentioning that you have to change BOTH event binders to .on() events, because if you only change the second one, it triggers after the first click. I'm guessing the .click() event happens first, then the .on() event is triggered after the class has been changed.
Thanks also to **Rory McCrossan** for the updated JSfiddle!